# Duplicate AWS S3 files differing only by a carriage return at the end of the Object URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an S3 bucket with *nearly* duplicate files:

[image]

If I run the AWS CLI, I get the same file paths, differing only by a few bytes:

```
2021-09-23 16:36:36     134626 Original/53866358.xml
2021-09-23 16:36:36     134675 Original/53866358.xml
```

If I look at the individual object pages, both have the same key:

[image]

[image]

The only difference is that one has `%0D` (ASCII carriage return) at the end of its Object URL. Presumably, this is the larger file. My question is: How can I get a unique reference to each of these using the AWS S3 CLI? I'd like to delete the ones with the carriage-return at the end.

Comment: Can't you just delete it in the S3 management console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem, just to lay the ground work of how my solution will help, I recreated the issue with a simple python script:

```python
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.put_object(Bucket='example-bucket', Key='temp/key', Body=b'normal key')
s3.put_object(Bucket='example-bucket', Key='temp/key\r', Body=b'this is not the normal key')
```

From there, you can see the issue as you describe:

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://example-bucket/temp/
2021-12-03 20:14:45         10 key
2021-12-03 20:14:45         26 key
```

You can list the objects with more details using the cli (some details have been removed from the output here):

```
$ aws s3api list-objects --bucket example-bucket --prefix temp/
{
    "Contents": [
        {
            "Key": "temp/key",
            "Size": 10
        },
        {
            "Key": "temp/key\r",
            "Size": 26
        }
    ]
}
```

To remove the object with the CR in the key name, a script would be easiest, but you can delete it with the CLI, just with a somewhat awkward syntax:

```
## If you're using Unix or Mac
$ aws s3api delete-object --cli-input-json '{"Bucket": "example-bucket", "Key": "temp/key\r"}'

## If you're using Windows:
C:> aws s3api delete-object --cli-input-json "{""Bucket"": ""example-bucket"", ""
Key"": ""temp/key\r""}"
```

Note that required syntax to quote the JSON object, and escape the quotes on Windows.

From there, it's simple to verify this worked as expected:

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://example-bucket/temp/
2021-12-03 20:14:45         10 key

$ aws s3 cp s3://example-bucket/temp/key final_check.txt
download: s3://example-bucket/temp/key to ./final_check.txt

$ type final_check.txt
normal key
```